# Display selected feature next to winform window

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, c#, arcgis-10.6

I'm trying to achieve a scenario like below image
when a row selected in Grid, the selected row's feature should be visible next to winform window
[image: Expecting Scenario]

But in my case, I'm stuck with a selected feature is back of grid form, the code so far I worked

```
private void zm2Feat(IFeature pFeat, IMap pMap)
        {
            IActiveView pActVw = (IActiveView)pMap; IEnvelope pEnv = null;
            try
            {
                //zoom to feat
                IPoint pPnt = (IGeometry)pFeat.ShapeCopy as IPoint;
                HIlightFeatures(pFeat.ShapeCopy, pMap);
                IPoint pnewPnt = new PointClass(); pnewPnt.X = pPnt.X + 50; pnewPnt.Y = pPnt.Y;
                ITopologicalOperator pTopoOp = (ITopologicalOperator)pnewPnt;
                IGeometry newGeom = pTopoOp.Buffer(50);
                pEnv = newGeom.Envelope;  pActVw.Extent = pEnv;
               clsGeneralFunctions.pMap.MapScale = 1000;
                pActVw.Refresh();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

How can I move selected feature next to winform window?

Comment: The geometry object and the form use different coordinates.. the geometry is a world location but the form is screen. You will need to do an IDisplayTransformation.FromMapPoint https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//001w000000t2000000 to get the screen coordinate *from the upper left of the ArcMap window* to reposition your form https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.desktoplocation?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with the same code, I just made changes in this line and it worked

```
IPoint pnewPnt = new PointClass(); pnewPnt.X = pPnt.X -300; pnewPnt.Y = pPnt.Y;
```